# Tokensize a string in python

Tags: python, typer

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
from typer import Option, Typer, echo
app = Typer(name="testapp")
@app.command("run", help="Run a command in my special environment")
def run(
    command: str,
) -> None:
    print (command)
```

When running this testapp using

`testapp run "foobar --with baz --exclude bar --myfancyotheroption"`

It works perfectly well because it accepts "command" as a string, instead I wish to be able to tokenize it and just run it as

`testapp run foobar --with baz --exclude bar --myfancyotheroption`

In the current content, I might have anything as a part of the command, so how do I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Context](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/commands/context/#configuring-the-context) :

```py
from typer import Typer, Context

app = Typer(name="testapp")

@app.command(
        "run",
        context_settings={"allow_extra_args": True, "ignore_unknown_options": True},
        help="Run a command in my special environment"
)
def run(ctx: Context) -> None:
    command = " ".join(ctx.args)
    print(command)
```

Comment: That didn't work and it errored out with 

"No such option: --with"

Comment: What does`print (pass)` do?

Comment: @CristiFati it was in the original code

Comment: @tandem sorry about that, I will correct it

Comment: @tandem I corrected the code